# jquery href with zend routes issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework

i found a free template called magister

when i have the href like this :

```
<li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
```

it works

but with a different url like this gives an error

```
<li><a id="contactos" href="<?php echo $this->url('application/contactos') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Contacts') ?></a></li>
```

i have this error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /application/contactos

i trying to make this work i need some help

```
var new_section =$($(current_item).attr('href'));                                          

alert(new_section);

new_section.fadeIn( section_show_time );


$("a", '.mainmenu').click(function() 
    {
        if( ! $(this).hasClass('active') ) { 
            current_item = this;
            alert('current : '+current_item);

            // close all visible divs with the class of .section
            $('.section:visible').fadeOut( section_hide_time, function() {
                alert('dentro do section visible');
                $('a', '.mainmenu').removeClass( 'active' );  
                $(current_item).addClass( 'active' );

                var new_section =$($(current_item).attr('href'));
                alert(new_section);

                new_section.fadeIn( section_show_time );
            });
        }
        return false;
    }); 


<section class="section" id="about">
```